# How to make protractor press the ESCAPE key?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I've tried this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();
```

but nothing happens.

I'm using this with SPACE Key and this works fine.

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SPACE).perform();
```

Answer (score 13):

There could be several reasons for it, but first of all, according to the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) of Protractor you need to execute the `sendKeys()` on an `ElementFinder`, so if the focus is on for example an input field you can do this

```
element(by.css('#-your-input-id')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE);
```

You can also do it on the body like this (`$` = shorthand for `by.css`):

```
$('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE);
```

Secondly there could be a problem with the UserInteraction API of your webdriver. In the past there were a lot of problems with the Firefox and Safari driver and with some versions of Chromedriver.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the same code as you have return, you can use this:

```
browser
    .actions()
    .sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE)
    .perform();
```

I hope this would work for you.

Since the sendKeys and Key is implemented using Keyboard class, the key values will differ for the OS May be.

The links below will give the name of the keys you have to give for the sendKeys:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you must send the ESC Key to any element?
At my app the following assignment works fine for a cancel button.

```
element(by.xpath('...')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

When in confusion like this, start looking into the source code..else do a console.log to get idea of what is provided by the framework.

Try this

```
console.log('**********');
console.log(protractor.Key);
console.log('**********');
```

Answer (score 0):

### basically what you have done is correct. try to write it like method and call this method because it is working fine for me.

selectEscapeKey: function () { return
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();},